# Cross Account AWS Lambda with IAM credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scope, amazon-iam

I have a cross account IAM question about running in a Lambda function.  (I know people may use STS assume, but this package really isn't worth protecting, and I don't want to go through linking the accounts)

Account “A”.

```
S3 – package “s3://foo/foo”

IAM credentials “pkg_creds” for bucket "s3://foo"
```

Account “B”

```
Lamba function “gogo” runs

In this Lambda function, it attempts to use boto3 and the pkg_creds to
download package “s3://foo/foo”, but if fails with this error:

 **The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.**
```

Lambda is read only, but I believe boto3 will not write credentials to ~/.aws if I'm using boto3.client (not session).  However, I also set the AWS_CONFIG_FILE to /tmp just in case.  It still fails.  I suspect what I'm proposing isn't possible because LAMBDA has immutable AWS credentials, where you can't change scopes, even one that is explicitly given to boto3.

Let me know your thoughts.  I may try do the job with Faragate, but Lambda function is easier to maintain and deploy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doing this properly and securely (with cross-account role trust) is not that much effort compared to doing it improperly and potentially insecurely (sharing IAM user credentials). PS what do you mean by "Lambda is read only"?

Comment: jarmod, thanks!  i totally want to adhere to good standard practices.  it actually a saas where i create buckets in other users account.  it's not like a one to few relationships.   the user provides the iam and then i create the bucket for them with my own lambda account.

Comment: sorry, when i google this error, it says boto3 is trying to write the credentials to home directory.  it is actually if i use boto3.session.  my bad. should have mentioned why i wrote read only.

Comment: They provide you with IAM user credentials for their account? Or they give your account (or your Lambda function's role) permission to assume an IAM role in their account and that assumed role gives you permissions on their S3 bucket? Or something else? The IAM user option works, but is not a good option. The second option is ideally where you want to be.

Comment: for onboarding, we walk them through a wizard.  they provide iam credentials.  they can delete im credentials after the onboarding, but we need it like token to create the underlying buckets for them.  if we have them create the buckets, it will be named incorrectly, no have encryption...etc.

Comment: Do you need one-time credentials just to set up the bucket and not beyond that? Are you asking them to provide IAM user credentials or do you also provide  an option for STS credentials?

Comment: we just prompt them for iam key and secret.  we don't know where it comes from.  but we don't want to establish an role for us to create the sts credentials in their behave.  for us, we just take key and secret and insert into boto3.client and create the buckets.  it doesn't work with lambda context.  not sure what i need to do or if i can do anything.

Comment: i guess we want a clean separation between our saas account and the user account if that makes sense.

Comment: OK, so presumably they give you access key and secret key for an IAM user in their account. You provide those to the boto3 service constructor per Mark B’s instructions and what happens? If it fails, have you tested this with IAM user credentials that *you* create, in *your* account? Show your code that uses these credentials.

Comment: yep, it fails exactly like mark suggested.   but it is inherited class, so let me do in the class inheriting it just in case.  i have an boto3 helper that establishes the client and resource for different products.

Comment: k..let me test right quick on the inheriting class and i'll post the code.  i mean, it's pretty much what mark suggested.

Comment: Include the exact exception and error message. And then test the same code with your own IAM user credentials, which you know are valid.

Comment: sorry..totally my bad.  the new credentials for my test account didn't have s3 permissions.  it works now.  so embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda isn't using a `~/.aws` config file at all, it is using environment variables by default. There are [many ways](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html) to configure AWS credentials in boto3. You should be able to create a new boto3 client in your Lambda function with explicit AWS credentials like so:

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCOUNT_A_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCOUNT_A_SECRET_KEY
)
```

And pass `ACCOUNT_A_ACCESS_KEY` and `ACCOUNT_A_SECRET_KEY` as environment variables to the function.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion mark!  i am actually doing this exact thing.  i think lambda is smart enough to limit the scope for itself, even one where i'm establishing an explicit connection to a different account.  let me double check.  the explicit connection is in an inherited class, though it works fine in an ec2 asg group.  i just rather go serverless these days.

Answer (score 0):

after troubleshooting more.  the issue was that i was took in the "environmental variable" SESSION which is set on the lambda function, but not on my ec2 instance.  so i was always using the lambda session key that seems to overide the explicit key and secret.

Answer (score -1):

User error.  I can verify boto3 in a lambda function can use credentials outside of its scope.